# Should I use beginTransaction while using @Transactional?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am quite confused with Spring and Hibernate transactions. I have the following sample code.

I am wondering if

1. This is a correct way of retrieval or not.
2. Should I use `getCurrentSession().beginTransaction()` as well, should I use it in conjunction with `@Transactional` at all?

**Configuration**

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:2000/HiberProject" />
        <property name="username" value="jack" />
        <property name="password" value="jack" />
    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hiberproject.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
  class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class SampleRecordsServiceImpl implements SampleRecordsService{

 @Autowired
 SampleRecordsRepository sampleRecordsRepository;

 @Override
 @Transactional(readOnly=true)
 public Record retrieveRecord(long id){
      return sampleRecordsRepository.retrieveRecord(id);
 }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public class SampleRecordsRepository implements SampleRecordsRepository{

 @Autowired
 SessionFactory sessioFactory;

 @Override
 public Record retrieveRecord(long id){
     return (Record) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Record.class,id);
 }
}
```

Comment: (Short answer): No.  (Longer answer) Spring has begun transaction for you under the hood so you do not need to do so.

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks, how about the second question

Comment: I think I have already said no

Answer (score 4):

The `@Transactional` annotation itself defines the scope of a single database transaction. The database transaction happens inside the scope of a persistence context.

The persistence context is just a synchronizer object that tracks the state of a limited set of Java objects and makes sure that changes on those objects are eventually persisted back into the database.

For `@Transactional` annotation  you can set propagation attribute, using [Propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) you can handle your tarnsaction in different way like `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`(if you need new transaction on every request) . the default propagation is `REQUIRED`.

`session.beginTransaction()` will also either begin a new Transaction if one isn't present, or it will use an existing transaction to begin the unit of work specified.

So you should use either one of approach to manage the transaction.

Comment: thanks, how about the second question. Also please explain more about propagation, when should I use other options?

Comment: No, you should not use both of the approach simultaneously. For propagation see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes that's Okay to use only `@Transactional` annotation like this when you use Spring to manage your transaction.
2. No. You don't need to do that! If you use `@Transactional` annotation in your service, then Spring takes care of your persistence layer to manage transaction. All you need is to declare persistence layer specific transaction manager in your Spring configuration. So you do not need to manage transaction with hibernate sessions by using `session.beginTransaction()` together with `@Transactional`.

For more information please see the [documentation of using `@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).