# Hibernate InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException while deleting an entity by the Id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I work with a RESTful web-service in Java/Spring and while trying to delete an entity object with the Id, I get the `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` error. The full error-stack is provided below,

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:55)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.deleteWalletInfoById(Unknown Source)
    at mobi.puut.services.WalletServiceImpl.deleteWalletInfoById(WalletServiceImpl.java:279)
    at mobi.puut.controllers.WalletRestController.deleteWalletInfoById(WalletRestController.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1496)
    at mobi.puut.database.WalletInfoDaoHibernate.deleteWalletInfoById(WalletInfoDaoHibernate.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 44 more
```

So, this is exactly what creates the issue,

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1496)
    at mobi.puut.database.WalletInfoDaoHibernate.deleteWalletInfoById(WalletInfoDaoHibernate.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

The hibernate connection is correct as everything else is working fine. The mentioned entity class is provided,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet_info")
public class WalletInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I use Java annotation based configuration and the classes provided below,

The configuration files are here,

**ApplicationConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.controllers"})
class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

//    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
//    public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
//        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
//    }

//    @Bean
//    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
//        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
//        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5242880);
//        return multipartResolver;
//    }

//    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
//    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
//        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
//        resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
//        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
//        return resource;
//    }

//    @Bean
//    public InternalResourceViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
//        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
//        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
//        bean.setSuffix(".html");
//        bean.setOrder(2);
//        return bean;
//    }
}
```

**DatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.database"})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"com.form.handler.entities"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
//
//        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
//        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
//
//        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.form.handler.entities"});
//
//        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
//        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
//
//        // set the hibernate properties for the project
//        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
//
//        return em;
//    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet1");
        dataSource.setUsername("testuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("testpassword");

        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**ServiceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.services"})
public class ServiceConfig {

}
```

**WebInitializer.java**

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class, ServiceConfig.class,
                DatabaseConfig.class);

        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher-servlet", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }

//  @Override
//  public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
//      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
//      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
//      rootContext.register(ServiceConfig.class, JPAConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
//
//      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
//      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
//
//      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
//      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
//      dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);
//
//      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
//      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
//      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
//      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
//
//  }
}
```

The relevant code in the `Service` directory,

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class WalletServiceImpl implements WalletService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private StatusDao statusDao;

    @Autowired
    private WalletInfoDao walletInfoDao;

    @Override
    public void deleteWalletInfoById(Long id) {
        walletInfoDao.deleteWalletInfoById(id);
    }
}
```

In the `Dao` directory, the code to delete by Id,

```
@Repository
public class WalletInfoDaoHibernate
        extends HibernateDaoSupport
        implements WalletInfoDao {


@Override
    public void deleteWalletInfoById(Long id) {

        try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            Query query = session.createQuery("delete WalletInfo where id = :id");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            int result = query.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Result = " + result);

        } catch (HibernateException e) {

            System.out.println("No result");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the `REST` controller from where I make the call,

```
// delete a wallet with the Id
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<WalletInfo> deleteWalletInfoById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.getWalletInfo(id);

        if (walletInfo == null) {
            System.out.println("The WalletInfo obj with id = " + id + " is not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfo>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        walletService.deleteWalletInfoById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfo>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

In the `POSTMAN` after making the delete request, I get the error,

[image]

In the `REST` method level, I tried with `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and in the class level  `@Produces({"text/plain","application/xml","application/json"})` with the `import javax.ws.rs.Produces;` Obviously, it didn't solve the issue at hand.

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
@Override
public void deleteWalletInfoById(Long id) {

    try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

        Query query = session.createQuery("delete WalletInfo where id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        int result = query.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Result = " + result);

    } catch (HibernateException e) {

        System.out.println("No result");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Actually you should not open session here (your service is annotated as @Transactional so session is opened there).
Use

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(...)
```

OR

manually start transaction and commit/rollback after the logic.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586852/should-i-use-begintransaction-while-using-transactional)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the delete method to,

```
@Override
    public void deleteWalletInfoById(Long theId) {

    // get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    // delete object with primary key
    Query theQuery =
            currentSession.createQuery("delete WalletInfo where id=:walletId");
    theQuery.setParameter("walletId", theId);

    theQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

Now, it's working fine